# Make shopt change local to function

Tags: bash, shopt

I'm trying to write a bash function that uses `nocasematch` without changing the callers setting of the option. The function definition is:

```
is_hello_world() {
  shopt -s nocasematch
  [[ "$1" =~ "hello world" ]] 
}
```

Before I call it:

```
$ shopt nocasematch
nocasematch     off
```

Call it:

```
$ is_hello_world 'hello world' && echo Yes
Yes
$ is_hello_world 'Hello World' && echo Yes
Yes
```

As expected, but now `nocasematch` of the caller has changed:

```
$ shopt nocasematch
nocasematch     on
```

**Is there any easy way to make the option change local to the function?**

I know I can check the return value of `shopt -q` but that still means the function should remember this and reset it before exit.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The function body can be any compound command, not just a group command ( `{}` ). Use a sub-shell:

```
is_hello_world() (
  shopt -s nocasematch
  [[ "$1" =~ "hello world" ]] 
)
```

Comment: `foo () {...}` just looks so natural, you never think that the braces aren't part of the function syntax, rather than the mostly commonly used compound command.

Comment: Will this impact performance due to process' context switching spawning a new shell?

Comment: @davide There will be some overhead in spawning new processes. However, if it becomes noticeable or problematic in your shell script, that's a sign that you should be using a different language. A good rule of thumb is that the running time of any shell script should be dominated by the programs it runs, not the shell itself.

Comment: You may prefer to store the old value and then restore it. Subshelling is inefficient, but in the particular case of Bash, under some circumstances, it optimizes the process call reusing the same process rather than forking. `$SHELLOPTS` and `$BASHOPTS` are your friends.

Comment: @chepner, indeed... what if `foo () { ( # ...; ); }`?

Comment: That doesn't clear it up. What you have is legal; it's not clear if you are asking why it is legal, or why you might want to use both a subshell and a command group, or what? Perhaps you could be specific, rather than cryptic?

Answer (score 27):

## Use a RETURN trap

> Commands specified with an RETURN trap are executed before execution resumes after a shell function ... returns...

> The `-p` option [to shopt] causes output to be displayed in a form that may be reused as input.

– https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

```
foobar() {
    trap "$(shopt -p extglob)" RETURN
    shopt -s extglob

    # ... your stuff here ...

}
```

**For test**

```
foobar() {
    trap "$(shopt -p extglob)" RETURN
    shopt -s extglob

    echo "inside foobar"
    shopt extglob # Display current setting for errexit option
}

main() {
    echo "inside main"
    shopt extglob # Display current setting for errexit option
    foobar
    echo "back inside main"
    shopt extglob # Display current setting for errexit option
}
```

**Test**

```
$ main
inside main
extglob         off
inside foobar
extglob         on
back inside main
extglob         off
```

**Variation:** To reset ***all shopt*** options, change the trap statement to:

```
trap "$(shopt -p)" RETURN
```

**Variation:** To reset ***all set*** options, change the trap statement to:

```
trap "$(set +o)" RETURN
```

Note: Starting with Bash 4.4, there's a better way: [make $- local](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406332/89782).

**Variation:** To reset ***all set*** and ***all shopt*** options, change the trap statement to:

```
trap "$(set +o); $(shopt -p)" RETURN
```

**NOTE:** `set +o` is equivalent to `shopt -p -o`:

> **+o**  Write the current option settings to standard output in a format that is suitable for reinput to the shell as commands that achieve the same options settings.
>
> – [Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition > set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)

Comment: This is a really excellent, useful answer. However, would `"$(set +o; shopt -p;)"` not work more correctly than `"$(set +o)$(shopt -p)"`? To see the difference, try `echo "$(set +o; shopt -p;)"` and carefully compare the result to that of `echo "$(set +o)$(shopt -p)"`. Specifically, examine the last line returned by *set* and the first line returned by *shopt.*

Comment: Good catch @thb. I added a semicolon between the `set +o` and `shopt -p` outputs.

Comment: More specific citations:
[`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)
[`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap)

Comment: Making `$-` local doesn't work for all cases, as it only reverts those options that are set via `set`, but not all options that can be set via `shopt` can be set via `set`.

Answer (score 14):

I know this post date from 2012, but you can also do the following (works in Git Bash 1.8.4 on Windows, so it should work on Linux) :

```
function foobar() {
    local old=$(shopt -p extglob)
    shopt -s extglob

    ... your stuff here ...
    eval "$old"
}
```

The `-p` option simply print `shopt -s extglob` if `extglob` is on, otherwise `shopt -u extglob`.

`shopt -p` print the whole list of options.

Comment: If there exists information that enhances the discussion it is always welcome. The solution you suggest, remembering the setting and changing it back, is what I was trying to avoid. I should have been more explicit about it. Anyway, it is worth keeping your answer as a good alternative of how to go about it. +1

Comment: For my case, I did not care about it and I admit this might be as bad as tempering with IFS. On the other hand, I suppose it would be easy to make a `pushshopt` function like there is a `pushd`, and use bash arrays to remember previous option before setting them. Like `pushshopt +extglob -nocasematch` and `popshopt`.

Comment: Note that if you use `set -e` and you separate the statement into `local old; old=$(shopt -p extglob)`, the second statement will error out because as `man bash(1)` states: "The return status when listing options is zero if all optnames are enabled, non-zero otherwise". In that case, you need to write something like `local old; old=$(shopt -p extglob || true)`. The reason it works when using one statement is that `local` swallows the return type of the right hand side (e.g. `local foo=$(false)` actually returns the zero status code); that's one of bash's many pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an associative array to remember the previous setting and then use it for reverting to the earlier setting, like this:

## shopt_set

```
declare -gA _shopt_restore
shopt_set() {
    local opt count
    for opt; do
        if ! shopt -q "$opt"; then
            echo "$opt not set, setting it"
            shopt -s "$opt"
            _shopt_restore[$opt]=1
            ((count++))
        else
            echo "$opt set already"
        fi
    done
}
```

## shopt_unset

```
shopt_unset() {
    local opt restore_type
    for opt; do
        restore_type=${_shopt_restore[$opt]}
        if shopt -q "$opt"; then
            echo "$opt set, unsetting it"
            shopt -u "$opt"
            _shopt_restore[$opt]=2
        else
            echo "$opt unset already"
        fi
        if [[ $restore_type == 1 ]]; then
            unset _shopt_restore[$opt]
        fi
    done
}
```

## shopt_restore

```
shopt_restore() {
    local opt opts restore_type
    if (($# > 0)); then
        opts=("$@")
    else
        opts=("${!_shopt_restore[@]}")
    fi
    for opt in "${opts[@]}"; do
        restore_type=${_shopt_restore[$opt]}
        case $restore_type in
        1)
            echo "unsetting $opt"
            shopt -u "$opt"
            unset _shopt_restore[$opt]
            ;;
        2)
            echo "setting $opt"
            shopt -s "$opt"
            unset _shopt_restore[$opt]
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$opt wasn't changed earlier"
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Then use these functions as:

```
... some logic ...
shopt_set nullglob globstar      # set one or more shopt options
... logic that depends on the above shopt settings
shopt_restore nullglob globstar  # we are done, revert back to earlier setting
```

or

```
... some logic ...
shopt_set nullglob
... some more logic ...
shopt_set globstar
... some more logic involving shopt_set and shopt_unset ...
shopt_restore             # restore everything
```

Complete source code here: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/shopt.sh