# shopt does not work inside shell function

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, shopt

I work on Ubuntu and using bash shell

I am trying to execute 'aliases' as shown below but it does not work

When I try 'shopt -s expanded_aliases; source env.sh; hal-on' outside function it works but inside a function it does not work

```
do_build()
{
source env.sh

shopt -s expand_aliases

hal-on
}

# Main
do_build
```

Error Message

- hal-on
  ./temp: line 10: hal-on: command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make shopt change local to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179633/make-shopt-change-local-to-function)

Comment: @IporSircer That does not seem like an obvious duplicate -- in fact it asks about quite the opposite --, although I suppose the accepted answer might be a suitable workaround here as well.

Comment: Using aliases in the first place is most obviously something you could be doing differently.  I'd hesitate to go so far as to call it out and out "wrong" but there are many, many other reasons to avoid aliases if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases have weird behaviour in bash and it is almost always better to use a function. What you have in your example is likely a definition of aliases within a function and I'm not sure what happens there.

Also, it's uncommon and problematic to source files within a function, unless its just a bunch of variable sets. In fact, unless you're explicitly declaring the variables to be "local", there's little difference to doing the source outside.

One case I can see that you might be in is to only do the things defined in the environment in a certain condition. and if your variable sets are complex I can see you not wanting to do that. But really restrict it to variable sets... no function/alias definitions.

Read up on aliases in the bash man page. Search for "Aliases are not expanded". It has something to do with "aliases are expanded at read time". With some experimentation, it appears that aliases are not expanded within a function even if the shopt is set before the function definition.

So... use functions instead.

`alias foo="bar baz"` becomes `foo(){ bar baz "$@" ;}` and generally operates identically.