# Is space special for pattern replacement in BASH?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, whitespace, trim

Trying to remove leading and trailing blanks (SPC) from a variable's value using BASH, I feel that it does not work as described.
I started with `${var%% }` and `${var## }` which should remove the longest pattern, but it seems only one blank is removed:

```
% val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val## }|"
|  a  | a  |
% val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val%% }|"
|  a  |  a |
```

Then I tried pattern matching which seems no remove nothing (they also should repeatedly remove a blank at the start or end of the value):

```
% val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val//# }|"
|  a  |  a  |
% val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val//% }|"
|  a  |  a  |
```

I feel I made some simple mistake, but it seems I'm sitting on my eyes: Why doesn't this work?

(I did already visit these answers, but they did not include "my solution":
[How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable),
[How to remove space from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659318/how-to-remove-space-from-string))

Comment: You are matching a single space. The matched string has to start or end from the start or end of the variable. Try `${val##  }"` or `${val## *}"`. As you can see in your example it is removing a single space.

Comment: @123: Actually I had tried that, too. But it removes everything!
`val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val## *}|"` outputs `|  a  ||` (and a single `#` produces `|  a  | a  |`). (`val="  a  ";echo "|${val}|${val## }|"` also doesn't work: `|  a  | a  |`)
I had tried all those before asking, so see the title of the question ;-)

Comment: yeah, best bet is to use extglob like in the answer below.

Comment: There are solutions to the underlying problem, but the question (Is space special for pattern replacement in BASH?) is still unanswered!

Comment: No as I explained above it is working exactly the same as any other character, you were just matching a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space (0x20) is not special for both glob patterns and RE patterns.

For your problem I would take advantage of the `extglob` shell option:

```
[STEP 108] # shopt -s extglob
[STEP 109] # v='    foo    '
[STEP 110] # echo "|${v##+( )}|"
|foo    |
[STEP 111] # echo "|${v%%+( )}|"
|    foo|
[STEP 112] # echo "|${v%%+([[:blank:]])}|"
|    foo|
[STEP 113] # echo "|${v##+([[:blank:]])}|"
|foo    |
[STEP 114] #
```

Comment: Nice! I tried to use the `extglob` syntax; and incorrectly tried the regex anchors `^` and `$` with parameter-expansion which didn't work. This is good!

Comment: This may be useful, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179633/make-shopt-change-local-to-function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that space (SPC) is handled specially; instead the problem is that **pattern** as used in the manual page of bash refers to **pathname patterns**, and not to **regular expressions** (unless `extglob` is set (which seems to be set by default)).  That is `' *'` is not a *sequence of blanks*, but instead it's *a blank followed by anything*.

The second problem is that "**the longest matching pattern**" is not determined by applying the match repeatedly until it fails, but only once. So if the pattern does not contain a `*`, `%` and `%%` produce the same result, just as `#` and `##` do).

The problems in `${val//# }` are:

- `//` and `/#` cannot be combined; only one variant can be used.
- *pattern* in `${parameter/pattern/string}` is not a regular expression, but  a **pathname pattern** (still).

This means that there is no benefit of using `${val/# }` over using
`${val# }`.  To remove all leading and trailing blanks the following (somewhat complex) code can be used:

```
val="  a  "
echo -n "|${val}"
while [ "_$val" != "_${val# }" ]
do
    val="${val# }"
done
while [ "_$val" != "_${val% }" ]
do
    val="${val% }"
done
echo "|${val}|"
```

So when using `extglob`, the solution looks like this (as pointed out in a previous answer):

```
al="  c  "
echo -n "|${val}"
val="${val##+( )}"
val="${val%%+( )}"
echo "|${val}|"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can archive this with `sed`.

To remove all leading empty space and empty spaces on the end of a string ...

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
```